# A circuit having 2 inputs and 2 outputs

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, multiplexer, power-electronics, logic-gates

I am going to design a circuit that should have 2 inputs and 2 outputs.

when both inputs are low both outputs should be low

when input 1 is high and input 2 is low, output 1 should be a square wave alternating between 0(low) and 1(high) with duty cycle 50%. output 2 should be low

when input 2 is high and input 1 is low, output 2 should be high. output 1 should be low

when both inputs are high both outputs should be low.

I need some of your ideas on how this is to be done.

This is what i have done so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmhnEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have done this is MULTISIM and both outputs works fine.

The issue is i want the period of the square wave form to be 0.5 seconds. I am using the equation f= 1/2.2R1C from this tutorial:

electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/generators.html

But i am not getting the desired period

Comment: As of now this question is too broad.  There are many different ways this can be done.  Do you have an constraints like circuit size, anything?

Comment: Do you want to do this with or without a microcontroller?

Comment: Write the **truth table** and you'll notice that output2 behaves like a NAND gate. So that leaves just the square wave generator. I assume you already have a fixed frequency clock to drive the system. So maybe a DFF configured to toggle at clk/2, with an output enable as per the truth table. So this could be implemented with discrete TTL logic chips, or a microcontroller, or even an FPGA.

Comment: why the tag power-electronics?  what does it have to do with that?  seems more like a logic exercise.

Comment: What frequency square wave?

Comment: @Funkyguy: There's nothing wrong with his question.  He's specified his inputs and his outputs adequately and asked for some help in realizing a solution. Not to be rude, but just because a solution isn't apparent to you doesn't mean there are too many to consider.

Comment: @EMFields Not rude at all.  I think you're misunderstanding why I asked for more information though.  After I read it I could have easily listed many different solutions, enough to the point where the question needed more specific information on the situation.

Comment: @RogerRowland I wont be using a micro controller

Comment: @MarkU output 2 is not a NAND gate

Comment: @Funkyguy I wont be using a microcontroller
i am planning to use ttl logic

Comment: @Funkyguy: I'll be looking forward to your contribution. :-)

Comment: @Funkyguy please take a look at my design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

[image]

"U1" on the '153 should read "U2", but Imgur was unhappy with my edited .png, so "U1" it stays.

The LTspice files are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7jn4pajgurxh419/AACKf1jqY2yypf4qeP9G7uESa?dl=0), and if you want to play with the circuit just download them all into the same folder and run the .asc file with LTspice.

Comment: In the strictest sense your design idea violates the 50% duty cycle requirement of the OUT1 due to the asynchronous gating of the square wave oscillator.

Comment: @EMFields  What is the circuit simulator that you have used here?

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure. :-) The simulator is LTspice, downloadable for free,[here](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) and the LTspice files you need to run the sim are [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7jn4pajgurxh419/AACKf1jqY2yypf4qeP9G7uESa?dl=0) Download them all into the same folder and run the .asc file with LTspice if you want to play with the circuit.

Comment: @EMFields please take a look at my design

Comment: @adrian: Your logic seems to be OK, but your oscillator seems suspect. Have you looked at the signal at the junction of R2 and NOT5? It should be a free-running square wave.

Comment: @EMFields I simulated the oscillator separately with its output directly given to an led and oscilloscope. It worked fine.

The problem is it does not work when it is connected to the 3 input AND gate.

Comment: @adrian Sorry, can't help you with that...

Comment: @EMFields Oh its alright, thank you very much. I found out the issue.
I had chosen NOT gates with voltage ratings of 2V.
I replaced them with NOT gates of ratings 6V.
That has solved the problem.
Now the whole full circuit is working as i expected it to do.

Comment: @EMFields i want the period of the square wave form to be 0.5 seconds.
I am using the equation f= 1/2.2R1C from this tutorial
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/generators.html.

But i am not getting the desired period.

Comment: @adrian: According to the tutorial, your equation should read: \$ f = \frac{1}{2.2\ R2\ C} \$ and R1 should be 10 megohms.